# Make a custom column with order item metadata Sortable in WooCommerce Order List (HPOS)

Tags: php, sorting, woocommerce, admin, orders

I wrote a code to add an item meta field in my Admin Order List in WooCommerce.

But I can't handle it to create a sortable column.

Code:

```
function display_wc_order_list_custom_column_content( $column, $order ){
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'my-column2' :
            // Get custom order metadata
            if ( ! empty($order) ) {
                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                    if (! empty($item->get_meta('wcrp_rental_products_rent_from'))) {
                        // Using WC_Data method get_meta() since WooCommerce 3
                        //echo $item->get_meta('wcrp_rental_products_rent_from');
                        $fulfilment_date = date_i18n( 'd. M Y', strtotime( $item->get_meta('wcrp_rental_products_rent_from') ) );
                        echo $fulfilment_date;
                    }
                }
            }
            // For testing (to be removed) - Empty value case
            else {
                echo '<small>(<em>no value</em>)</small>';
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I can add a sortable function to my Column:

```
add_filter( 'manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_sortable_columns', 'rudr_sortable_column' );
function rudr_sortable_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['my-column2'] = 'eventdate';
    return $columns;
}
```

But I dont understand how I can make it sortable.

If I look to the WooCommerce code, I find some hint with this Snippet in woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php at Line 587

```
// Sorting.
if ( isset( $query_vars['orderby'] ) ) {
    if ( 'order_total' === $query_vars['orderby'] ) {
        // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
        $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, array(
            'meta_key'  => '_order_total',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
        ) );
        // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    }
}
```

I dont understand, how I can create from an item meta order field a sortable column. I hope that somebody have an idea.

Comment: Sortable columns work only with order data or order metadata, but not with order item metadata. So you need when the order is placed, to save that custom order item metadata as custom order metadata too…

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec for your hint. I write a Code for this. But it don't work. Maybe you have an idea wy it don't working?